# Hide mesh faces while maintaining collision

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, mesh, physics, cloth-simulation

I am animating a character and using a cloth simulation for their clothing. Part of their body mesh will occasionally clip through the cloth, which I would typically solve by sculpting or hiding the mesh entirely. However, I need the mesh to still affect the cloth simulation realistically, thus I am unable to change the physical shape of the mesh. Also, part of the body mesh must remain visible and outside of the clothing, thus making it impossible to simply mask out the entire mesh.

Is there a way to make specific faces of the body mesh invisible, while retaining the realistic collision properties of the original mesh?

Both eevee or cycles are an option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a *Mask* modifier: Assign the vertices that you want to make invisible to a vertex group, choose this vertex group in the modifier, and click on the arrow (<->) next to the group name in order to invert the selection:

[image]